# How to use random to choose if you want to go to an bonus question or not to go to the bonus question

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason if I start this code and if the Random choose "no" it would still go with the "yes" and go through the bonus question if you need more details ask.
Its python just saying

```
import random

a = "yes"
b = "no"
mylist = [a, b]

def keuze():
    print(random.choices(my_list))
    if "yes" in mylist:
        print("je krijgt een bonus vraag")
        print("Bonus vraag")
        print("In which year was Google launched")
        print("a. 2005")
        print("b. 1995")
        print("c. 1969")
        print("d. 1998")
        answer4 = input("Type here your answer: ")
        if answer4 == "d" or antwoord4 == "D":
            print ("Good your answer is right you get 1 extra chance")
            chance = chance + 1
        else:
            print("Ow sorry, your answer is wrong")
            chance = chance - 1
    else:
         print("The computer didn't chose to give you an bonus question")
example()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `"yes"` is always in `mylist` (you are asking if `"yes"` is in `["yes", "no"]`).
You may try it saving the `random.choices(mylist)` result into a variable and testing if that variable equals `['yes']`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tryed it but couldnt get what i needed so i chanced it to if the contestant wants even an bonus question.

like this.

```
def example():
    print("Do you want an bonus question?")
    bonuss = input("Type here yes or no: ")
    if  bonuss == "yes" or bonuss == "Yes":
        print("U will get an bonus question")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Bonus question 1")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("In wich year is google launched")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("a. 2005")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("b. 1995")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("c. 1969")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("d. 1998")
        time.sleep(1)
        antwoord4 = input("Type hier je antwoord: ")
        if antwoord4 == "d" or antwoord4 == "D":
            print ("Amazing your answer is right you get 1 extra chance")
            chance = chance + 1
        else:
            print("Ow your answer is wrong")
            chance = chance - 1
    else:
        print("U have chosen to not have an bonus question on to the next question")
example()
```

Comment: Oof i just got the sulution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i used `random.choices(list)`
so what i did to solve it was just to remove the s of `choices`
and i chanced the list to just an string
import time
import random

```
a = "yes"
b = "no"

list = a, b

rdm = random.choice(list)

def example():
    print(rdm)
    if  rdm == "yes":
        print("U will get an bonus question")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Bonus question 1")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("In wich year is google launched")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("a. 2005")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("b. 1995")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("c. 1969")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("d. 1998")
        time.sleep(1)
        antwoord4 = input("Type hier je antwoord: ")
        if antwoord4 == "d" or antwoord4 == "D":
            print ("Amazing your answer is right you get 1 extra chance")
            chance = chance + 1
        else:
            print("Ow your answer is wrong")
            chance = chance - 1
    else:
        print("U have chosen to not have an bonus question on to the next question")
example()
```